# Theoretical distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Martin has $n$ words, and he wants to make a computer program that chooses for him $k$ words (and shows them to him), where $k \le n$, for as many times as he clicks a button until all of the words are shown at least once. Every time the words are chosen, some of them can be repeated. So, he needs to find after how many attempts all the words will be shown at least once. If the $X_{n,k}$ is the random variable that shows the number of series until all the words are shown at least once, what's the theoretical distribution of it?

Comment: For $k=1$ it's a standard Coupon's Collector problem. $k>1$ is just an accelerated version.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem
This is what you mean, right?

Comment: The distribution of $X_{n,k}$ depends on the distribution of the $k$-subsets selected by the computer each time, and you have not said what this distribution is (or even if it is to be randomly selected).  Potentially there is some word that will never be shown.  Was the tag `normal-distribution` intended to contribute to the problem formulation?

Comment: Well we don't know that distribution. The computer selects different k-subsets until all the words are shown at least once. This random variable must be discrete, because it's values can be 1,2....